How can I use Mistral AI open model without Hugging Face transformers library
I'm trying to make chat with 'Mixtral-8x7B-Instruct-v0.1' pre-trained model,
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer
from transformers import TextStreamer, GenerationConfig, PreTrainedModel
import torch
import time
import warnings


warnings.filterwarnings(action='ignore')


device_ids = [0, 1]  # Modify this list according to your GPU configuration
primary_device = f'cuda:{device_ids[0]}'

model_id = 'mistralai/Mixtral-8x7B-Instruct-v0.1'

torch.cuda.set_device(primary_device)

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_id)
tokenizer.add_special_tokens({'pad_token': '[PAD]'})

model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_id, load_in_4bit=True, device_map="auto")
print(f' ### type model : {type(model)} ###' )
model = torch.nn.DataParallel(model, device_ids=device_ids)

it_while = 0

messages = []
streamer = TextStreamer(tokenizer)

generation_config = GenerationConfig(
    temperature=0.8,
    top_p=0.8,
    top_k=100,
    max_new_tokens=512,
    early_stopping=True,
    do_sample=True,
)

print(f'###### generate type : {type(model.module.generate)} ######')
while True:
    
    
    input_prompt=input("Enter your message: ")
    messages.append({"role": "user", "content": input_prompt})
    start = time.time()
    
    
    print(f'--{it_while}--'*20)
    q = f"[INST]{messages} [/INST]"
    gened = model.module.generate(
        **tokenizer(
            q,
            return_tensors='pt',
            return_token_type_ids=False
        ).to('cuda'),
        generation_config=generation_config,
        pad_token_id=tokenizer.eos_token_id,
        eos_token_id=tokenizer.eos_token_id,
        streamer=streamer,
    )

    result_str = tokenizer.decode(gened[0])
    
    
    print(f'--{it_while} spend: {time.time() - start}' * 10)
    
    messages.append({"role": "assistant", "content": result_str})
    it_while += 1

that is running well, but I want modify print(generate) part.
So I want to know how can I use mistral models without transformers library for modify (other than print) ...
I tried to use the official github 'https://github.com/mistralai/mistral-src' . But I don't know how I can quantize the model to Int8 through the 'bitsandbytes' library.
